# I can't run my spring boot app because web.xml file is showing an error and I don't know why

Tags: java, spring-boot, web.xml

My web.xml file is showing an error and I don't know why. When I go to the file it showing red x on line two on the word "<web-app". When I hover on the error it showing this message below.

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>
> - cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'version' must appear on element 'web-   app'.
> - Attribute:
> - version is required in element:
> - web-app Code:

Here's the code for my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" id="WebApp_ID">
    <display-name>springboot-server</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

*In the problem tabe is showing two different errors is in the web.xml line two. The first type of error is* **Language Servers** *and the second type error is* **XML Problem**.

Comment: I think you need to specify the web-app version within the beginning tag. `<web-app version="2.4" xmlns.......`

Comment: @arooney88 can you please specify how the web-app version within the beginning tage need to look? Here's how the beginning of the web-app code look base on your suggestion. `<web-app  version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" id="WebApp_ID">` I did add the version and still showing error after I save it.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the version and put it after the xmlns file and I restart my project and the error was solved. Here's how the new code looks like with the issue solved.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" version="2.4" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" id="WebApp_ID">
    <display-name>springboot-server</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```